# How to control servlet execution by URLs?

Tags: java, servlets

If the `urlPatterns` controls basic URL rewrite, can I not use `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL?  I'm looking at this code: http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee/servlet

```
...
@WebServlet(name = "GuestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/guest"})
public class GuestServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
```

This page works great when I access `http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/guest`, but what if I wanted to do `http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/guest/edit?id=4`, how would I set that up in this controller?

In PHP the logical steps would be `http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/controller/function`.  In java it seems like I can only use `doGet()`, is this right?

I'm trying to envision how the overall URL structure affects the execution of controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resource http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

basically you need to change

```
@WebServlet(name = "GuestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/guest"})
```

to

```
@WebServlet(name = "GuestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/guest", "/guest/edit"})
```

now your servlet should handle the "/guest/edit" URL pattern also

Comment: Do I still need to put all my code within the `doGet()` or can I have say, a `doGetEdit()`?

Comment: whenever a "get" request is made the doGet() method is invoked, when a "post" is made, doPost() is invoked, for examples please go to http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html and download demos so that it will help you better understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use an URL pattern of `/guest/*` and use [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) to extract the path information.

Here's a kickoff example (trivial checks omitted):

```
@WebServlet("/guest/*")
public class GuestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        String action = pathInfo[1]; // edit
        String id = pathInfo[2]; // 4
        // ...
    }

}
```

Invoking http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/guest/edit/4 will set `action` to `edit` and `id` to `4`. You could from this step on make use of the strategy pattern to invoke specific business actions.

You could of course also go for an action based MVC framework which abstracts all the servlet boilerplate away, such as Spring MVC.

#### See also:

- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)